# Will a factory data reset make my camera working again?

Tags: camera, sony-xperia

I was having low memory on my Sony Xperia phone and while emptying space, I removed some files related to the phone camera. Since then it is showing the following error on starting the camera -

> Error - Camera not available.

I would not like to delete all my personal data unnecessarily, otherwise.

Comment: What are those "some files related to the phone camera" you've removed? Is the device rooted? Did you remove system files (with root powers)? In the latter case, a factory reset won't bring them back – you would have either to replace the files you've removed or, if you don't have them anymore, reflash your ROM. Btw: removing ***system*** files doesn't help with the [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) issue, as that only affects `/data`.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should (of course) back up your personal data first!

2) Yes. A factory reset/clean should do the trick. That is: if the camera worked during your last system clean.

Comment: What is a system clean? I think I never did any system clean so far.

Comment: By "system clean" I mean if you rooted your phone and started cleaning out unwanted files and programs.

If you haven't done anything system-wise since you bought your phone and if the camera worked fine then: A factory reset should do the trick.